# How to trigger the function if input field value is changed by another function?

Tags: javascript, html

Team,

Please help,

i have

```
<input type="text" name="item_num" id="item_num" onkeyup="changeVal(this.value)" />
```

to trigger this function after keypress

```
function changeVal(str) {
 document.getElementById("find_item").value = document.getElementById("item_num").value ;
}
```

now

```
<input type="text" name="find" id="find" value="" onchange="getHint(this.value)" />
```

but it does not trigger it, the onchange cant trigger getHint function.

is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing `event and function`=> `event != function`

> 1. `onchange` is the event .its performing by a user action
> 2. At the time textchange the event performing the function .but only `target.element`, not for others.
> 3. So you could trigger the next `input` `onchange` event at the time of `first` input typing

you need to trigger the event like this below in snippet

```
 document.getElementById("find").onchange()
```

```js
function changeVal(str) {
  document.getElementById("find").value = str;
  document.getElementById("find").onchange()
}
function getHint(str){
console.log('second one changed')
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="item_num" id="item_num" onkeyup="changeVal(this.value)">
<input type="text" name="find" id="find" onchange="getHint(this.value)">
```

Comment: i am so sorry i had you confused. just a beginner starting to make a program not familiar yet.

thank you so much. because of your sample i got now what i wanted it to happen.